# How to find what kind of parameters is required for undocumented version of handleGesture selector (for UIWebView)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, gestures

I have added a custom popup menu to UIWebView instance:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture::)] autorelease];
}

- (void)handleGesture
{

}

- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [gestureRecognizer.view becomeFirstResponder];
        UIMenuController* mc = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [mc setTargetRect: gestureRecognizer.view.frame inView: gestureRecognizer.view.superview];
        [mc setMenuVisible: YES animated: YES];
}
```

And it works! Until I focus textarea (CodeMirror editor) on a webpage. At this case I have the following exception:

```
-[FirstViewController handleGesture::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20369c00
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FirstViewController handleGesture::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20369c00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3608c2a3 0x3439c97f 0x3608fe07 0x3608e531 0x35fe5f68 0x3747ad31 0x374423dd 0x3762f479 0x37366837 0x3736529b 0x360616cd 0x3605f9c1 0x3605fd17 0x35fd2ebd 0x35fd2d49 0x3650f2eb 0x373b1301 0x140bb 0x14060)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I think it's required to implement undocumented version of handleGesture selector with exotic parameters. Is it right? How to find what kind of parameters is required?

Comment: I hope you're not planning on submitting this to the app store. Use of undocumented APIs is grounds for immediate rejection.

Comment: [App store approval guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html): "2.5  Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected"

Comment: But it's your app. If you want to take the chance and hope they don't notice, that's your right. I just wanted to make sure you weren't surprised when you get rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code:

```
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)] autorelease];
```